# forks and its functionality?

Tags: c, fork

I have the following code and am asked to how many times "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" will be printed

```
fun() {
  printf("A");
  fork();
  printf("B");
  if (fork() != 0) {
     printf("C");
     fork();
     printf("D");
  }
  printf("E");
}
```

so it should be:

```
A
A 
B
E
```

im not sure if my answer above is correct? and what the line `if(fork() !=0 )` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 thread prints a, 2 threads print b.  each of the 2 forks, but only the 2 parents go into the if statement and print c.  Each of those two fork and all 4 procs print d.  Then, each of the 6 procs (two children from if-fork and 4 threads coming out of if print e.

You can't determine the order, but the number of each letter is:

A x1

b x2

c x2

d x4

e x6

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork):

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

The line `if (fork() != 0) { ... }` is checking to make sure the current process is not a child of the original forking process. Only the parent process will execute the code in this block.

This works because `fork()` returns a PID in the parent process, a 0 in the child process, and -1 on error.